# JavaScript regexp, replacing all character except given selection.

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all characters in a string apart from English alpabets. My current regex is of the nature, `'ab-aml1'.replace(/![a-zA-Z]/g,'')`. I would expect this to return `abaml`. However it returns the entire string passed to it. How can I do a negation selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript's logical NOT operator will not work in RegEx. If you want any other data apart from alphabets to be removed, you can use `[^a-zA-Z]`. It is called [negated character set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-negated-character-set) and it means that, anything which is NOT `a-zA-Z`.

```
console.log('ab-aml1'.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,''));
```

**Output**

```
abaml
```

Comment: Oh, I assumed `^` would only be for matching starting with. I forgot the dual usage! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @thefourtheye possibly clear `\W` instead of `[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @Grundy `\W` will not remove the number `1` :)